# How can I let ipset entries "age"?

Tags: firewall, ipset

I am trying to establish a whitelist of clients that have successfully logged into the system, using `ipset`. What options do I have to let an entry age so that I can later discard it based on its age?

Is there a better method than the idea outlined below?

I have not found anything provided by `ipset` directly, so I am trying to establish whether or not such a facility exists within the scope of `ipset`/`iptables`.

---

Right now the only idea I have come up with is to use a cronjob that swaps the list every X minutes or hours. So as an example I'd have a list `whitelist` which is active, plus a list for the next hour (say for 21:00 `whistelist_21`), if I am some time between 20:00 and 20:59. Any client connecting *now* would be added to the active `whitelist` and to the whitelist for next hour (or a given period). Then at each full hour (or given period) a cronjob - e.g. at 21:00 in the above case - swaps the existing `whitelist` for the `whitelist_21` one and disposes of the (now renamed) `whitelist`. E.g.:

```
ipset swap whitelist whitelist_21
ipset destroy whitelist_21
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the `man` page describes what I was looking for. It's aptly called `timeout` and can be specified when adding entries to an IP set. I missed it due to a search for wrong terms.

A default timeout value can be given when creating a set and later for each entry added - if it is desired to override the set default.

Examples from `ipset(8)`:

```
ipset create test hash:ip timeout 300
ipset add test 192.168.0.1 timeout 60
ipset -exist add test 192.168.0.1 timeout 600
```